# Retrieve the HTTP referrer URL using Scotty

Tags: haskell, scotty

`$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` allows one to retrieve the referring URL in PHP, how to do the same in Haskell?

Comment: What have you tried, can you include some code, [etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aside: you probably want [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-3.2.1.1/docs/Network-Wai.html#v:requestHeaderReferer), but that requires you to parse the header yourself.

Comment: Can't you use the `header` function provided in `scotty` [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty-0.11.0/docs/Web-Scotty.html#v:header)? E.g. `url <- header "referer"`? Note that `url` will then be of type `Maybe Text`.

Comment: Thank you, it was just that. I didn't know this information was in the header so I didn't look in that direction.

Comment: @liminalisht can you please write an actual answer, then it can be accepted get taken off the unanswered list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http_referer` is stored in the HTTP header, which means that you can retrieve it using the header `function` of `scotty` like this:

```
url <- header "referer"
```